# Как указать ссылку на диапазон, адреса границ которого записаны в ячейках

Tags: excel, vba

Подскажите пожалуйста , как решить проблему.
Есть такой код:

```
Dim item_map() As Variant      
str = CStr(Sheets("RUN").Cells(7, 2)) & ":" & CStr(Sheets("RUN").Cells(7, 3))
      Set MyRange = Range(str)
      item_map = Sheets("ITEM_MAP").Range(MyRange)
```

где

`Sheets("RUN").Cells(7, 2)` - значение в ячейке A2

`Sheets("RUN").Cells(7, 3)` - значение в ячейке C185

При выполнении макроса вылетает ошибка *runtime error 1004*

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()
    Dim item_map()
    Dim MyRange As Range

    With Sheets("RUN")
        Set MyRange = Sheets("ITEM_MAP").Range(.Cells(7, 2).Value, .Cells(7, 3).Value)
        item_map = MyRange
    End With

    ' здесь издеваемся над item_map'
    Set MyRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Ссылка на ячейку (`Cells(7, 2)`) и значение ячейки (`Cells(7, 2).Value`) - не одно и то же. Да, ссылка по умолчанию принимается как значение, но не в этом случае. Попробуйте из кода удалить `.Value`... Поэтому правильно `.Value` всегда указывать явно.

Comment: Не забывайте объявлять переменные